# JPA/Hibernate with externally generated identifiers

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm expected to expose through Spring Boot 2.5 a legacy relational schema where the primary key is computed by the DBMS on the basis of an identity field along the following lines:

```sql
create table items
(

    serial      int identity,

    id          as '/items/' + convert(varchar(12), serial) persisted primary key,

    …

)
```

My issue is that JPA/Hibernate seem to assume that the primary key is always going to be generated on the server side and we [don't apparently have a suitable generation strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-GenericGenerator):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public static class ItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy="{???}")
    private String id;

    …

}
```

Any chances of instructing JPA/Hibernate just to accept the generated value without trying to write it?

Comment: Which is the primary key column?

Comment: `id` (fixed code snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the IDENTITY strategy is for. This strategy assumes that the ID is generated in the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public static class ItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String handle;

    …

}
```

Comment: And [here's](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html) the relevant doc.

Comment: Awesome. I was under the impression that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` was reserved for actual identity columns.

Comment: Unfortunately the scheme can't be applied with `@Inheritance(strategy=TABLE_PER_CLASS)` as it's not compatible with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` , but that's another story…

Comment: You shouldn't use TABLE_PER_CLASS anyway because this leads to bad performance when selecting on the parent entity